# How to make Generic Object in java implements an interface

Tags: java, generics

I want to have a generic object that implements an interface.
I mean if i have a class A

```
class A<E> {
    E x;
}
```

I want to make sure that x will implement a particular interface(myInterface). In other words, that the type E implements an interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class A<E extends MyInterface>
{

}
```

That's it, quite simple..

Comment: Huh. Strange it uses extends there, and not implements.

Answer (score 14):

```
class A<E extends MyInterface> {
    E x;
}
```

I initially thought you were looking for:

```
class A<E> implements MyInterface {
   E x;
}

or

class A<E> implements MyInterface<E> {
   E x;
}
```

as appropriate.